# Discord Bot Command Ignored?

Tags: python, discord, bots

I started to work on building a Discord Bot using Python and I can't for the life of me figure out why it is not reacting to commands. I have googled and read various questions on here about DMing users and all I've found are what looks to be conflicting answers. I have looked at YouTube videos and copied code for code.

I have tried to set up DMing a user, a role and even just a simple command like ping and pong. Nothing.  I have set Intents both in the code and in Developer Tools to All/On and still nothing.

I have an event setup that when a certain word is said the bot responds with a random.choice of a list which is working fine.

```
import nest_asyncio
nest_asyncio.apply()

import discord
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from discord.ext import commands

import random
import os


load_dotenv()
TOKEN = os.getenv('DISCORD_TOKEN')
GUILD = os.getenv('DISCORD_GUILD')

intents = discord.Intents.default()

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!", intents=intents)

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    guild = discord.utils.find(lambda g: g.name == GUILD, bot.guilds)
    print(
        f'{bot.user} is connected to the following guild:\n'
        f'{guild.name}(id: {guild.id})'
    )

@bot.command
async def ping(ctx):
        await ctx.send('pong')
```

Comment: I think you will need `intents.message_content = True`

Comment: I tried adding that but just get: AttributeError: 'Intents' object has no attribute 'message_content'

Comment: What is your discord version? I think you will need a relatively modern one to use that.

Comment: Everything is up to date, I actually managed to solve the issue ... I think? I compared it with the script of another python discord bot and ran the other one which worked just fine, no issue at all. 
I believe the issue was actually that bot.command and bot.event need to end in (), I'm also wondering if the placement of a command after event causes an issue but I am not sure on that.
Thanks for the help though! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To anyone else who finds this as I did see others across my browsing have similar issues:

**1**
Make sure the `@client/bot.command` have () at the end of them.

**2**
There are guides on discord bot building with python however whilst helpful it does appear most are somewhat out of date to newer versions of Python/Discord.py.

Comment: The `@event` decorators shouldn't need the `()`. The positioning also shouldn't matter (unless you don't `process_commands` in `on_message`, which you do need to do that if you overwrite it)

Comment: Ah yes, I was looking at the wrong thing when I typed that haha I've edited it now :)